# How to redirect a PointerProperty to Object when the owner is Linked

Tags: python, library-overrides

I'have a pointer to object initialized on an armature like this:

```
bpy.types.Armature.myPointer = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type = bpy.types.Object)
```

When I link the Armature with library override (together with the object in question) the pointer is still pointing to the original object, where I need it to point to the new object (the linked one).

How can I 'redirect' the pointer if the armature is linked?

p.s. Already triyed to add override = {'LIBRARY_OVERRIDABLE'} to the definition

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a deficiency in library overrides. Built-in pointers (parents, constraint targets, etc) are remapped correctly via system overrides, but not custom properties.

The workaround is to manually define a user override (rmb on your data, option at the top of the menu in blender 3.3).

It would be great to get a better answer...

Comment: In Blender 3.3 they work nicely. Define the pointer in the original file with  {'LIBRARY_OVERRIDABLE'}. 
In the linked file right click on the linked folder -> library override -> make -> select and content. Then right click on the armature and do the same.